# Отправляю команду npm rub build высвечивается это и ничего не собирается

Tags: node.js, npm

C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed>npm run build

> ui@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
at module.exports (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
at module.exports (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\dednet\DN-RAGE-UI-master-fixed\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.6.0

Comment: Поставьте node v16 и не мучайтесь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69719852/4496422